# In a game, how do 2 factors interact when both influence your likelihood of a win?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving, game-theory

Suppose a game exists such that the stronger of the 2 players is 60% likely to win and the taller of the 2 is 70% likely to win. In this world, height and strength are completely independent of each other.

How likely is a player to win, if he is :

A) the stronger but shorter player ?

B) the taller AND stronger player ?

... and so on.

I am trying to figure out how the two factors will interact with each other. I am very interested in this question so I can prove a point in an argument. I tried to solve it on a whiteboard but nothing came to mind. I don't know how to google this kind of thing either, so could someone please help? Thanks!

Comment: Height and strength that a person receives may be independent of each other but it is not clear from context that height and strength independently influence the outcomes of a match.  The end result is that you will have to decide on a model and experimental results can influence your opinion on whether your choice of model was appropriate and that there is not nearly enough information to solve with what is written here.

Comment: You have effectively given us events $A,B,C$ for being stronger, taller, and the winner respectively., we can assume no exactly equal heights/strength etc... so $\Pr(A)=\Pr(B)=\Pr(C)=0.5$, you have given $\Pr(C\mid A)=0.6,\Pr(C\mid B)=0.7$ and you ask $\Pr(C\mid A,B)$.  Expanding $\Pr(C\mid A,B)=\dfrac{\Pr(A\cap B\cap C)}{\Pr(A\cap B)}$ and at this point we are stuck.  We can expand the denominator as $0.25$ based on assumption of independence of strength and height, but we can not expand the numerator via an independence assumption since we *know* they are not independent.

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you. I see now that this is not nearly enough information to decide an answer!